# WSO2 payload factory mediator not transforming a certain json format to another

Tags: json, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, payload

I have created an api using wso2 integration studio to get user details from a mock server created using mockoon [image]
first it will send a userId to the endpoint "getUserDeets" by appending the userI to the end of the URL. Then mockoon with send a json response back.

I want to get the mockoon json response and format it to a certain json format using the payload factory mediator. Below is the source code for the above mentioned api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/myHRM" name="GetUserInfo" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/user/{userId}">
        <inSequence>
            <!-- <call>
                <endpoint key="getUserDetails"/>
            </call> -->
            <log level="full">
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.userId')" name="ucscserId"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="getUserDeets"/>
            </call>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>
                  {
                     "userId": "$1",
                     "name": "$2",
                     "address": "$3",
                     "mobile": "$4"
                  }
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.user.userId"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.user.username"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.user.residence"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.user.phone"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
            <!-- <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/> -->
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

I get the below error when calling the API

```
2023-07-04 10:57:43,269]  INFO {AuthenticationHandlerAdapter} - User admin logged in successfully
[2023-07-04 10:57:55,158]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:GetUserInfo} To: /myHRM/user/1000, MessageID: urn:uuid:6e62eec3-9ecb-4992-9f54-edb983effc9b, correlation_id: 6e62eec3-9ecb-4992-9f54-edb983effc9b, Direction: request, ucscserId = 1000, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
[2023-07-04 10:57:55,171]  INFO {TimeoutHandler} - This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2023-07-04 10:57:55,238] ERROR {OMSourcedElementImpl} - Could not get parser from data source for element jsonObject javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected symbol:END_OBJECT
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.<init>(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:88)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonDataSource.getReader(JsonDataSource.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getChildren(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:862)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:660)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:668)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeChildrenFromPayloadBody(JsonUtil.java:926)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:905)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:1026)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:139)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:111)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:242)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:820)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:322)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected symbol:END_OBJECT
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.require(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.next(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.peek(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:243)
    ... 26 more

[2023-07-04 10:57:55,289] ERROR {SequenceMediator} - {api:GetUserInfo} Existing json payload is malformed. MessageID : urn:uuid:fec54f7c-d3ee-4c2a-aea1-535c5d807227 org.apache.synapse.commons.SynapseCommonsException: Existing json payload is malformed. MessageID : urn:uuid:fec54f7c-d3ee-4c2a-aea1-535c5d807227
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeChildrenFromPayloadBody(JsonUtil.java:931)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:905)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:1026)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:139)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.PayloadFactoryMediator.mediate(PayloadFactoryMediator.java:111)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:242)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:820)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:322)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:627)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:298)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error obtaining parser from data source:java.io.IOException: Unexpected symbol:END_OBJECT
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getChildren(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:862)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:660)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:668)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeChildrenFromPayloadBody(JsonUtil.java:926)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected symbol:END_OBJECT
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.<init>(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:88)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonDataSource.getReader(JsonDataSource.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:224)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected symbol:END_OBJECT
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.require(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.next(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.stream.impl.JsonStreamSourceImpl.peek(JsonStreamSourceImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:151)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:154)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:243)
    ... 26 more

[2023-07-04 11:00:56,185]  INFO {SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2023-07-04 11:00:56,186]  WARN {SourceHandler} - STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /myHRM/user/1000, HTTP_METHOD = POST, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /127.0.0.1:56205, CONNECTION http-incoming-4 Correlation ID : 6e62eec3-9ecb-4992-9f54-edb983effc9b
```

Comment: can you add information about  <endpoint key="getUserDeets"/> ?
and add the log behind the endpoint getUserDeets ?